# How do I get SQLLite to ingore a Postgres specific migration?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm running Rails 5 and Postgres 9.4.  I have this Postgres migration so that I could do LIKE searches for rapidly ...

```
class AddTrgmIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE INDEX trgm_idx_person_name ON people USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
    SQL
  end
end
```

However, when I attempt to run a unit test (using minitest), SQLLite isn't liking my Postgres specific syntax and is throwing the below error

```
localhost:myproject davea$ rails test test/controllers/people_controller_test.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 68189
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "gin_trgm_ops": syntax error: CREATE  INDEX "trgm_idx_person_name" ON "people" (name gin_trgm_ops)
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:137:in `execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `block in execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:590:in `block in log'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:583:in `log'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:232:in `execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:713:in `add_index'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:282:in `block in create_table'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:281:in `create_table'
```

Is there a way I can tell SqlLite to ignore the migration or is there some other way of rewriting it that would make both databases happy?

Comment: You could catch that exception... but mostly people solve this by making sure their local test environment matches their prod environment... because otherwise you'll never be able to test all the same aspects work the way they should.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, You can check the Database type using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_values["config"][:adapter]
```

Which you can use to conditionally run the migration.

however I also agree with Taryn's comment

Comment: But I already know the database type is SQLLite based on the error.  Is that what you're explaining?

Comment: After creating the "AddTrgmIndex" migration, were you able to apply those changes successfully to the DB.